# Merging two api call results when result is an array

Tags: angular

I have working angular code which merges two API results where the second call is dependent on the first. It's a simple join operation:

```
class myPerson {
  constructor(
     public name: string,
     public planet: string){}
}

let person = http.get<myPerson[]>('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(
      person => http.get(person['homeworld'])
        .pipe(
          map(planet => 
          {
            return new myPerson(person['name'], planet['name'])
          })
        )
    )
  )

  person.subscribe( 
    result => console.log(result)
  )
```

The output is, correctly:

```
myPerson {name: "Luke Skywalker", planet: "Tatooine"}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-switchmap-merge-results-multiple-http-reque-6xz4a6

However, I've become completely stuck when it comes to extending this to handle an array of results from the first API call (https://swapi.co/api/people/). The closest I've come is as follows:

```
  tmpObs: Observable<any[]>


  http.get<any[]>('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(people => 
    {
      let planets = people['results'].map( person => {
        return http.get(person['homeworld']) 
      })
      this.tmpObs = of(people)
      return forkJoin(planets)  
    })
  ).subscribe( planets =>
  {
    this.tmpObs.subscribe( people => {
      console.log(people, planets)
    })
  }
)
```

But the use of the temporary observables array seems wrong and the information I need is in the subscription to the API call. How can I create an observable array of myPerson? Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I would take.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StarWarsService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getPeople() {
        return this.http.get<any>('https://swapi.co/api/people/').pipe(
            map(people => {
                people.results.map(person => this.http.get<any>(person.homeworld).subscribe(
                    homeworld => person.planet = homeworld
                ));
                return people;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

This service makes an http call to get the people, then loops (using map) through those results to get the home world and assign it to the planet property for each person.

Here's how you can consume the service above in a component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StarWarsService } from '../shared/star-wars.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-star-wars',
    template: `<div *ngIf="people$ | async as people">
      <pre>{{ people | json }}</pre>
    </div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./star-wars.component.css']
})
export class StarWarsComponent implements OnInit {
    people$: Observable<any>;
    constructor(private starWarsService: StarWarsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.people$ = this.starWarsService.getPeople();
    }

}
```

The async pipe in the template handles the subscribe/unsubscribe. Works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Here for the rescue:

you are very close with your solution. The only problem is that you didn't take both returns. I would do something more in the line of (not exact, because I'm not 100% sure what you are going for):

```
    return forkJoin(this.getPeople(), this.getPlanets())
  .pipe(
    tap(([people, planet]) => {
      const data: StarWarsData = {
        'person': people,
        'planet': planet
      };
      this.starWarsData.next(data);
    }),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not following it. I don't think I can do the forkJoin as you suggest since the getting of the planet is dependent on first getting the person.  It's driving me mad because in SQL terms it's a trivially simple task: SELECT pe.name, pl.name FROM people pe, planets pl where pe.homeworld = pl.name  (or something along those lines) . I'm after (what should be) a simple extension to my working example where get an array of myPerson rather than a single one.